# Android Studio(flutter project) - how find all cyrillic's string resource(for localization)?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, localization

I am working with an existing project. In this project all string resources are "scattered" in the code, example:

```
 child: Text('тест'),
```

now I need to add localization for these strings - then find them. these lines are symbols in Cyrillic.
the first option I try is to find these characters using regular expressions. i used the following options:

```
[\p{IsCyrillic}]
\p{IsCyrillic}+
```

but this does not find all the words in Cyrillic. Perhaps you can suggest other options (another regular expression)? I would love to automate this - but I don't know how yet.